# QGIS loading a layer every 5 seconds (Threading)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, multithreading

Im trying to load a point layer from a CSV-file with a QGIS Plugin every 5 seconds. The Coordinates in this CSV-File which are used to locate the point layer are changed every few seconds.
I tried to work with a while(True) loop and a timer (5 seconds), but QGIS is freezing then because of this infinite loop.
After a lot of research I found out that I need to work with multi-threading (?). I tried a lot, but I am unable to make it working. How can I get the plugin running in the background and make QGIS still usable?

**Edit**:

This is the part in the plugin where I load the layer from the csv:

```py
    if(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Ambulance1')):
            layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Ambulance1')
            rr = layers[0]
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(rr)
            #LadenDerCsv-Datei
            uri = "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/koordinaten2.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude"
            vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Ambulance1','delimitedtext')
    
            #QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) #Qgis2
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) #QGIS3
    
            #SymbologieAendern
            renderer = vlayer.renderer()
            symbol = renderer.symbol()
            symbol = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Gesundheitseinrichtungen/Krankenwagen/ambulance.svg")
            symbol.setSize(8)
            symbol.setFillColor(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
            symbol.setStrokeColor(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
            symbol.setStrokeWidth(1)
            vlayer.renderer().symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol)
            expression = """
            Longitude : [% "Longitude" %] <br>
            Latitude : [% "Latitude" %]
            """
            vlayer.setMapTipTemplate(expression)
    
            vlayer.triggerRepaint()
            #ZoomaufErstelltenLayerVersion2
            vlayer.selectAll()
            mCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
            mCanvas.zoomToSelected()
            vlayer.removeSelection()
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if you load a CSV file using the GUI, there is an option to "watch" the file, which updates the canvas automatically when the file is modified. The "watchFile" option is available in the QgsVectorLayer class in PyQGGIS https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html

Comment: Thank you ! That is exactly what I need, because the file is changed every 5 seconds from a GPS tracking tool. How can I implement the "watchFile" option in my plugin ?

Comment: You are going to have to share snippets of your code I suppose to at least show how you are reading the CSV file. I'm still a beginner in PyQGIS and didn't get to the plugin development yet, so hopefully, other PyQGIS experts will chime in.

Comment: You can edit your original post to add code or additional details to your questions. Answers are, well, for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watchFile option, as mentioned in the documentation should be added to the uri string.

This is an example of how to add the option to your uri string:

```
uri = "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/koordinaten2.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}&options={}".format(",", "x", "y", "watchFile=yes")
```

However, the refresh only happens when you pan the canvas while with the GUI, the refresh happens without pan. I'm not sure if there is anything that can be added to the code to trigger the refresh when the file changes, perhaps add signals?

Answer (score 1):

Complementing answer of [Techie_Gus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/52014/techie-gus), you can activate option "Refresh Layer in interval(Seconds)" in CSV layer properties -> rendering menu.

[image: LayerProperties]

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works now !